# Switch webpack source map depending on dev / production mode

Tags: webpack, config, webpack-dev-server, production, source-maps

I want to know how to instruct my webpack config to run a different source map for development and production modes.

As it is I am just commenting out the one I don't want, which is obviously pretty inconvenient, I would like this decision to be taken dynamically depending on the npm script that I am running - production server, or webpack dev server.

I already have a variable which corresponds to development mode (`const debug`), but I'm not sure how to use this in my config to determine a different source map.

Here's my current config...

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"; 

 const webpack = require('webpack'); 
 const path = require('path'); 

 module.exports = { 
     //  devtool: 'eval-source-map',  
     devtool: 'source-map', 
     entry: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app-client.js'), 
     devServer: { 
       inline: true, 
       port: 3333, 
       contentBase: "public/static/", 
       historyApiFallback: { 
         index: '/index-static.html' 
       } 
     }, 
     output: { 
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'static', 'js'), 
       publicPath: "/js/", 
       filename: 'bundle.js' 
     }, 
     module: { 
         loaders: [ 
             { 
                test: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), 
                loader: ['babel-loader'], 
                query: { 
                  presets: debug ? ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre', 'stage-2'] : ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'] 
                } 
             }, 
             { 
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
                loaders: [ 
                   'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]', 
                   'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false' 
                ] 
             } 
          ] 
     }, 
     plugins: debug ? [] : [ 
       new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
         'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) 
       }), 
       new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), 
       new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(), 
       new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
         compress: { warnings: false }, 
         mangle: true, 
         sourcemap: false, 
         beautify: false, 
         dead_code: true 
       }), 
    ] 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.NODE_ENV` in `webpack.config.js` is set only if you provide the environment variable `NODE_ENV` when invoking webpack, e.g. using `NODE_ENV webpack` in your `package.json`. If you need to support Windows as well, use the [`env-variable`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-variable) package.

See also the the guide on [building for production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/) for details and other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR - A `webpack.config.js` file can export a function that has 2 parameters. Either of these parameters can be used to dynamically set config options when webpack is invoked.

- The first parameter being an [environment](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options) that can be set to `production` or `development` (or any other value). I.E `$webpack --env production`.
- The second parameter being an options map that can be used to access any passed options. I.E. `$webpack --mode production`.

More info, examples, and links to helpful docs below:

This applies to webpack 5 (but I think may also apply to webpack 4). All this info I got from the [webpack Configuration Types](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) docs, particularly the very first section "Exporting a Function".

The following example is directly from the webpack docs. They don't use the NODE_ENV variable, but instead use the webpack `env.production` variable to set the `mode` config option to `'production'` or `'development'` accordingly. Setting the `mode` config option "sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` on `DefinePlugin` to [`production` or `development`]." Check [these docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) for more info.

```js
module.exports = function(env, argv) {

  return {

    mode: env.production ? 'production' : 'development',

    // Note that they also set devtool here based on the env variable
    devtool: env.production ? 'source-map' : 'eval',
     plugins: [
       new TerserPlugin({
         terserOptions: {

          compress: argv.mode === 'production' // only if `--mode production` was passed
         }
       })
     ]

  };
};
```

If you use the above example to set the mode and the devtool, you should be able to remove the `DefinePlugin` from the `plugins` array entirely, as these options will include and set the plugin automatically behind the scenes for you. However, if you want to keep your config as similar to its current setup as possible, you could simply use the ternary operator to set the `devtool` option:

```js
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"; 

const webpack = require('webpack'); 
const path = require('path'); 

module.exports = { 
    // dynamically set devtool based on debug status
    devtool: debug ? 'eval-source-map' : 'source-map', 
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'app-client.js'), 
    devServer: { 
      inline: true, 
      port: 3333, 
      contentBase: "public/static/", 
      historyApiFallback: { 
        index: '/index-static.html' 
      } 
    }, 
    output: { 
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'static', 'js'), 
      publicPath: "/js/", 
      filename: 'bundle.js' 
    }, 
    module: { 
        loaders: [ 
            { 
               test: path.join(__dirname, 'public'), 
               loader: ['babel-loader'], 
               query: { 
                 presets: debug ? ['react', 'es2015', 'react-hmre', 'stage-2'] : ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'] 
               } 
            }, 
            { 
               test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
               loaders: [ 
                  'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]', 
                  'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false' 
               ] 
            } 
         ] 
    }, 
    plugins: debug ? [] : [ 
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) 
      }), 
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), 
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(), 
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ 
        compress: { warnings: false }, 
        mangle: true, 
        sourcemap: false, 
        beautify: false, 
        dead_code: true 
      }), 
   ]
```